# Is this sentence correct in the way that "and" is used?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, academia

"It is a relatively inexpensive process, and also preserves the involved materials in the solid-state, avoiding possible phase limitations."

It doesn't sound so good to me, but I am not a native speaker. I was thinking that maybe like this sounds better: 
 "It is a relatively inexpensive process, **WHICH** also preserves the involved materials in the solid-state, avoiding possible phase limitations."
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I agree with you "and" and "also" are conjunctions which have similar meanings, there's too much redundancy. "Which" works fine. Take the [tour] and when you have plenty of free-time, browse the [help] to get to know how we work. Welcome to EL&U.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment!

Comment: In short, I think the **also** should be removed in any of the formulations.

Comment: This is a matter of style and opinion. That said, it is probably a majority opinion of school teachers and newspaper editors that it is a clumsy, poorly worded, misapplied parallelism. It is not incorrect, but it is probably not preferred good writing style.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question.